# How can I change the below function to output alphanumerically?

Tags: javascript

If I change the values to say 100a or 1a2b the input into the field track stops working.

I am wondering how I can make this work with alphanumeric values.

```
<select id="trackfull">
    <option value="none">none</option>
    <option value="visa">visa</option>
    <option value="mastercard">mastercard</option>
    <option value="discover">discover</option>
    <option value="americanexpress">americanexpress</option>
    <option value="jcb">jcb</option>
    </select>


<!-- Selection for full track start -->
<script> 
function updatePrice (el, priceLog, priceList) {
priceLog.value = priceList[el.getElementsByTagName('option')[el.selectedIndex].value.toLowerCase()];
}

var card = {
'visa' : 100,
'mastercard' : 200,
'discover' : 300,
'americanexpress' : 400,
'jcb' : 500
};

var select = document.getElementById('trackfull'),
hidden = document.getElementsByName('track')[0];

select.addEventListener('change', function(){
updatePrice(select, hidden, card);
});
</script>  
<!-- Selection for full track end -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Strings, and should be wrapped with quotes:

```
var card = {
    'visa' : '10a0',
    'mastercard' : 'b200',
    'discover' : '300',
    'americanexpress' : '400',
    'jcb' : '500'
};
```